# ChromeWebStoreに機能拡張を公開したのですが古いバージョンから置き変わらない

Tags: chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

ChromeWebStoreに機能拡張を公開したのですが古いバージョンから置き変わらず、同じ名前の機能拡張が二つ公開されてしまいました。

バージョン番号は1.0.1→1.0.2へと変更したのですが、同じ名前でバージョン番号があったとしても、IDがないといけないようで、同じIDであれば、置き変わるというところまでは、調べたのですが、そのIDをどこにどのように記述するか分からないのです。manifestに入力するのかなと調べてみても見つからず。どうすればいいのか分からないのです。

<manifestの一部>

```
  "manifest_version":3,
  "name": "FLOW PAGE",
  "version": "1.0.2",
  "description": "Speech (Auto Read & Auto Scroll) ",
  "default_locale":"en",
```

Answer (score 0):

Chrome Web Store デベロッパー ダッシュボードの「アイテム」のページで「＋ 新しいアイテム」でアップロードしてしまったのではないでしょうか。

[image: 新しいアイテム]

アイテムをアップデートするには、そのアイテムを選択し、左のメニューの「パッケージ」をクリックして、「新しいパッケージをアップロード」をクリックして新しいバージョンのzipファイルをアップロードします。

[image: 新しいパッケージをアップロード]

Comment: ありがとうございます。無事、更新バージョンをアップロードできました。